# iap - conversion from objective c to swift

Tags: objective-c, swift, in-app-purchase, ios8

I'm trying to convert my app from objective c to swift, and i have everything except for the in app purchase working.
i have the objective c helper class imported in the project, but i'm having trouble doing the RequestProductsCompletionHandler section

in the old objective c version i have the code

```
[[MTIAPHelper sharedInstance] requestProductsWithCompletionHandler:^(BOOL success, NSArray *products) {
    if (success) {
        _products = products;

        if([[self appData] isPro] == FALSE)
            [[self bUpgrade] setUserInteractionEnabled:TRUE];
    }
}];
```

and i'm trying to convert this section to objective c but so far i've been unable to convert the requestProductsWithCompletionHandler part

can anyone help?

i've tried creating the completion handler the same was as in objective c using

```
requestProductsWithCompletionHandler(sucess: Bool, products : NSArray)
```

but i get the compiler errors "Extra argument 'products' in call" and "Expected member name or constructor call after type name". 
if i try it without the parameters i get "Missing argument for parameter #1 in call"

Comment: What have you tried and where exactly are you running in to trouble? Are you getting compile errors? Runtime errors?

Comment: i've tried creating the completion handler the same was as in objective c using "requestProductsWithCompletionHandler(sucess: Bool, products : NSArray)" but i get the compiler errors "Extra argument 'products' in call" and "Expected member name or constructor call after type name". if i try it without the parameters i get "Missing argument for parameter #1 in call"

Comment: Ok. It would help if you edited your question and added the code that you tried along with that error. That way it's easier for us to see where you are coming from and point you in the right direction.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Swift, your completion handler would be a [closure](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Closures.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH11-XID_152). The syntax is semi-similar to blocks in Objective-C but, instead of defining the parameters outside the block:

```
^(BOOL success, NSArray *products) { /* ... */ }
```

you define them inside the closure:

```
{ (success: Bool, products: [AnyObject]!) in /* ... */ }
```

So, your call to `requestProductsWithCompletionHandler` should look something like this:

```
MTIAPHelper.sharedInstance().requestProductsWithCompletionHandler {
    (success: Bool, products: [AnyObject]!) in

    if success {
        // etc.
    }
}
```

You can also let Swift infer the parameter types for you:

```
MTIAPHelper.sharedInstance().requestProductsWithCompletionHandler {
    (success, products) in

    if success {
        // etc.
    }
}
```

Comment: cool. I'm getting the error '[AnyObject]!' is not a subtype of 'NSArray' though